# Formula for Google Charts histogram

Tags: charts, statistics, google-visualization, histogram, binning

What formula does Google Charts use to construct its histogram? For example, does it use Sturge's rule? Doane's rule? Scott's rule? etc. Is there any documentation on how it constructs it default bin size, min, and max?

Here is a link to the [`Histogram`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram) page for Google Charts.

> Google Charts automatically chooses the number of bins for you. All bins are equal width and have a height proportional to the number of data points in the bin. In other respects, histograms are similar to column charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the histogram section in the [notes for the October 1, 2018 release](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#october-1,-2018).

> Generate buckets using tick generation algorithm. Default number of buckets is computed using a new `histogram.numBucketsRule` option. Possible values are `'sqrt'`, `'sturges'`, and `'rice'`. See [Histogram: Number of bins and width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Number_of_bins_and_width)

Comment: thanks, do you know which of the three it uses as a default?

Comment: From the current documentation at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram#configuration-options, the default is currently `sqrt`.